# Installing Go Language

Tags: installation, go

I'm trying to install Go language, but at the end, I got these errors (I won't copy all because are a lot of lines):

```
$>=========== fixedbugs/bug359.go
 > BUG: errchk: fixedbugs/bug359.go:19: missing expected error: '"unexported field"'
 > errchk: fixedbugs/bug359.go:25: missing expected error: '"a redeclared"'
 > errchk: unmatched error messages:
 > ==================================================
 > fixedbugs/bug359.go:12: import /home/anju/go/pkg/linux_386/container/list.a:
 object is [linux 386 release.r56 9441] expected [linux 386 release.r60.3 10088+]
 > ==================================================
 0 known bugs; 78 unexpected bugs; test output differs
 FAILED
```

I've followed step by step the instructions, but always I get the same results. I edited my .bashrc with ne next lines:

```
export GOROOT=$HOME/go
export GOARCH=386
export GOOS=linux
export GOBIN=$HOME/bin
export PATH=$GOBIN:$PATH
```

But when I execute the command uname -a, I get these:

```
$Linux Anju 2.6.32-35-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 11 15:27:15 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux.
```

So, GOARCH=386 it's ok or maybe I should use another value? 
Thanks for the attention and excuse me my bad english.

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so, select an answer or answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

The standard default for `$GOBIN` is:

```
export GOBIN=$GOROOT/bin
```

You probably have multiple versions of Go installed. For example, `[linux 386 release.r56 9441]` and `[linux 386 release.r60.3 10088+]`. Therefore, you probably have multiple versions of Go binaries such as `8g`, perhaps in both `$HOME/bin` and `$GOROOT/bin` (`$HOME/go/bin`).

Answer (score 0):

i found a tutorial but i am not comfortable with terminal so can't figure it. http://www.kelvinwong.ca/2009/11/12/installing-google-go-on-mac-os-x-leopard/